# animate layour parameter with ObjectAnimator

Tags: android, android-animation

I have a card view and I want to animate the android:layout_marginTop of it. Here's the xml

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/maps_cardview_id"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="75dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
    android:visibility="visible"
    tools:background="#ff0000">
```

I tried this with the ObjectAnimator

```
            View view = (View)mCardViewContainer;
            ObjectAnimator animObj = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(view, "translationY", 0, -200);
            animObj.setDuration(300);
            animObj.start();

            animObj.addListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
                @Override
                public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                    mCardViewContainer.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
            });
```

but this is not what I need. It is moving the cardview translation. Is there a way to use the ObjectAnimator to animate just the "android:layout_marginTop"?

any pointers are greatly appreciated.

thx!